# Using method from App class in separate form xamarin

Tags: xamarin, methods

I am a beginner, so this should be an easy fix for someone with experience.
I am a veterinarian trying to build an app for vets to use. I am trying to learn via youtube and previous posts online, but I cannot find a solution for my roadblock:
I am trying to call a method already written in the App class:
Settings form binds a volume of onhand penicillin.
Usage form displays that volume, and asks the user to enter a volume used.
On button click I need the onhand volume to be 'updated' but i can't call the method in the App class (which has a get and set)
I have simplified for easier evaluation:

App code behind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace methods
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private const string penicillin = "penicillin";

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }

        public string Penicillin
        {
            get
            {
                if (Properties.ContainsKey(penicillin))
                {
                    return Properties[penicillin].ToString();
                }
                return "";
            }
            set
            {
                Properties[penicillin] = value;
            }
        }
}
}
```

Settings Form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="methods.Settings">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Penicillin Onhand" ></Label>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Penicillin}" Keyboard="Numeric" ></Entry>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Settings Code behind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace methods
{
    public partial class Settings : ContentPage
    {
        public Settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = Application.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="methods.Usage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Penicillin Held" ></Label>
        <Label x:Name="Held" Text="{Binding Penicillin}" ></Label>
        <Label Text="Penicillin Used" ></Label>
        <Entry x:Name="Using" Placeholder="ml" Keyboard="Numeric" ></Entry>
        <Button Text="Use" Clicked="Used_Clicked"></Button>
        </StackLayout>    
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Usage Code behind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace methods
{
    public partial class Usage : ContentPage
    {
        public Usage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = Application.Current;
        }

        void Used_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var VUsed = double.Parse(Using.Text);
            var VHeld = double.Parse(Held.Text);
            var Remaining = VHeld - VUsed;

            //how do i code the following? Error:'App' does not contain definition for Penicillin????
            App.Penicillin.value = Remaining;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try creating an object of the class App before calling the Penicillin property?

Comment: You are a wonderful human being, thank you.            
var Remain = Remaining.ToString();
            var app = new App();
            app.Penicillin = Remain;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a new instance of App - Xamarin Forms already maintains a reference to the current instance

```
((App)Application.Current).Penicillin = Remaining;
```

Comment: I appreciate your help Jason. Your approach might explain how the Onhand penicillin value loses persistance (as I was calling a new instance of App), however I get the following error (red underline) on your code text value: string does not contain a definition for 'value' and no accessible extension method 'value' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found.